# OleDb ORDER BY RND() is not Work (C#)

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-order-by, oledb, oledbcommand

Hello and Thank you for helping.

I'm using the following code in my Data set Data Table Query (by Wizard) for sorting by random(ID Column).

```
SELECT        ID, Q, A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, Correct
FROM            Quiz
ORDER BY RND(Quiz.ID)
```

When I test this code in Query-builder(in C#) Work Correctly but When I'm run my project this code not work and not load by random.
my using code for load:

```
this.quizTableAdapter.Fill(this.dBDataSet.Quiz);
```

Please help Me.

Comment: What is the given message / error / exception / behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error. Just Don't Order random and order from 1 to ... . 
I'm using the Sqlite.